# XMLtable with Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, oracle11g

Here is a sample table:

```
create table xmltemp (mydoc xmltype)
```

Here is a small xml doc for it:

```
insert into xmltemp values (
xmltype
('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<countries>
  <country>
    <name>Canada</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>US</name>
    <states>
      <state>
        <name>Washington</name>
        <name>Oregon</name>        
      </state>
    </states>
  </country>
</countries>
')
)
```

Notice that Canada does not have a 'states' element but the US does.
I'm trying to get these query results (order and formatting is not important):

```
Canada,
US,Washington
US,Oregon
```

When I execute this, I see both Canada and the US in the result:

```
select
countryname
from xmltemp,
xmltable('/countries/country' passing mydoc
   columns countryname varchar2(10) path 'name')
```

When I do this, I get both the states:

```
select
statename
from xmltemp,
xmltable('/countries/country/states/state/name' passing mydoc
   columns statename   varchar2(20) path '.') c
```

I tried this to get both country and states, but it seems oracle does not like the '..' syntax:

```
select
statename
from xmltemp,
xmltable('/countries/country/states/state/name' passing mydoc
   columns statename   varchar2(20) path '.',
           countryname varchar2(20) path '../../../name') c
```

Heres the error:

```
ORA-19110: unsupported XQuery expression
```

When I try this, I get the 'multi-item' error because of the two states:

```
select
countryname,
statename
from xmltemp,
xmltable('/countries/country' passing mydoc
   columns countryname varchar2(10) path 'name',
           statename   varchar2(20) path 'states/state/name') c
```

Here is that error:

```
ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton 
sequence - got multi-item sequence
```

What's a query that will get me my desired output of:

```
Canada,
US,Washington
US,Oregon
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select      X.COUNTRYNAME, Y.STATENAME
from        XMLTEMP
           ,xmltable('/countries/country'
                     passing MYDOC
                     columns COUNTRYNAME varchar2(20) path './name', 
                             STATES xmltype path './states') X,
            xmltable('/states/state/name' passing X.STATES 
                    columns STATENAME varchar2(20) path '.') (+) Y
```

Because you have multiple states you should join to another xml table. As some countries have no states then it needs to be a left outer join. I'm using the old method of `(+)` as I'm trying this on 10g and it seems there's a problem using `left outer join` in 10g but apparently it should be fine in `11g`.

Comment: Thanks.  I considered the outer-join yesterday, but couldn't quite figure it out.  Although they are not specific to Oracle I found these two links helpful, too: [Part 1] (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0708nicola/) [Part 2] (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0709nicola/)

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer as I cannot find that 11g supports parent addressing in any form in the PATH clause. Basically, what is being done here is that the parent records are loaded into an XMLTABLE with the child elements contained inside an XMLTYPE column in that result. Then, using the XMLTYPE child column from the parent records, load the child records into another XMLTABLE.  Oracle then implicitly joins all tables. --- What I am finding, however is that 11g does not outer joins properly with just one (+), I must put (+) on both x and y tables, which does not make much sense.

Comment: Another oddity I found with 11g is that I cannot address elements by specific attribute as expected when using a default xmlnamespace. The workaround is to address the attribute with the wildcard namespace (the explicit namespace does not work either). For example, does not work: PATH 'ID[@type="user"]'. Does not work: PATH 'ID[@foo:type="user"]'. Works: PATH 'ID[@*:type="user"]'.