# query xmltable oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, xmltable

I have a query that used XML input to generate a XML table, I give that table an alias "XMLalias". How can I query this table in some other select statement, which is part of same batch.

I want to do something like " select * from XMLalias ".

I am new to oracle so please excuse if this is something really simple.

thanks.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm

Comment: Thanks i have gone through this. but my question is how to query the xmltable alias.

Comment: Here is another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321391/xmltable-with-oracle-11g

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you need exactly as i figure what you want is one of this two:

```
select * from
      (select * from XMLalias ) insider
where insider.col1  /*.....*/
```

Or  you wanted someting like that

```
    select * 
        from XMLalias  a,
             XMLalias  b
where a.key_col=b.other_key_col
and  a.col1 = /*......  */
and  b.col2 = /*......  */
```