# Retrieving XML into Oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on a project where I have to write a stored procedure that retrieves data from a HTTP, XML service. the data needs to be returned in a table or cursor so clients can read it. I have done some work already retrieving the data from the service using UTL_HTTP. What I don't know how to do is to transform that data from XML into columns and rows. I have been searching the internet and find a lot of examples on querying an Oracle data  table and returning XML using XMLElement; but not the other way.
Thanks!

Comment: What you're looking for is `XMLTABLE()`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321391/xmltable-with-oracle-11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

One way is to write a parser (maybe in a differnt language like Perl or Java) which translates the XML into INSERT Statements.

In PL/SQL it can look like this:

```
your_xml := XMLType('<emp Id="1"><first>Peter</first><last>Fox</last></emp>');

insert into emp (empid, first_name, last_name)
select EXTRACTVALUE(your_xml, '/@Id'), EXTRACTVALUE(your_xml, '/first'), EXTRACTVALUE(your_xml, '/last') 
from dual;
```

I know `EXTRACTVALUE` has been deprecated in Oracle 11.2 but I just want to illustrate the principle.

Another way is to save the entire XML document into a table (simple INSERT statement) where you created a column of data type `XMLTYPE`. Then you create a view on this table using the functions you already found by your searching. With `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` is it also possible to update the XML document stored in table.